# UITable Matlab - Accessing specific cell

Tags: matlab, uitableview, indices

I am getting the row index of the selected cell with this code:

```
row = eventdata.Indices(1);
```

I can also get the column index by changing the 1 to 2. But I want to be able to get the content of any cell I want in that specific row without the user having to actually click on that specific cell but rather anywhere in that row. Let's say I want to get the data from the first column which in my case represents the ID.

In pseudo code it would look like:

```
x = getRowOfSelectedCell
field = Indices(x,1);
```

Say the selected row is 5. The variable field would consist of the value of the cell in the first column in row 5.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
function ScriptTest

d = rand(10,7);
t = uitable('Data', d,  'Units', 'norm', 'Position', [0,0,1,1]);

RequiredColumnIndex = 5;
set( t, 'CellSelectionCallback', {@TableSelectionCB, RequiredColumnIndex});

function TableSelectionCB(hTable, eventdata, RequiredColumnIndex)
    rowIndex = eventdata.Indices(1);
    TableData = get(hTable,'Data');

    field = TableData(rowIndex, RequiredColumnIndex);
    fprintf(' Value in cell [Row %d /Col %d ] is %f \n',  rowIndex, RequiredColumnIndex, field);
end

end
```

Here I decided to retrieve the data in column 5 (as you suggested) and printed the corresponding cell value in the command window.